# Map HTML input date to LocalDate of Java Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, localdate

I have a input field (type: 'date') - who could I map it to a 'LocalDate' field in my Object using Thymeleaf?

**Object**

```
public class Project {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private LocalDate startDate;

    private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

**HTML input**

```html
  <form action="#"
      th:action="@{|/admin/projects/add/save|}"
      th:object="${newProjects}"
      method="POST"
      class="form-horizontal">
        
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate"
                       placeholder="Project start"
                       th:field="*{startDate}"/>

    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate"
                       placeholder="Project start"
                       th:field="*{endDate}"/>
                       
</form>
```

How could I map the input field correctly to the LocalDate startDate or endDate?

**Controller**

```
//GetMapping for Projects is also there, but I didn't paste it to keep clarity

@PostMapping("/add/save")
public String saveProject(@Valid @ModelAttribute("project") Project project,
                          BindingResult bindingResult,
                          Model model,
                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

// bindingResult has error, because Thymeleaf can't map from the input-field to startDate

  if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      project.save(project);
      return "redirect:/admin/projects/list";
  } else {
      return "admin/projects/add";
  }
}
```

**Exception**

> *Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'startDate'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.LocalDate] for value
>   '2017-09-08'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Parse attempt failed for value [2017-09-08]*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a few options:

1 - Try:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate startDate;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate endDate;
```

2 - [Use Thymeleaf Extras](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time)

Comment: Great! Just make sure I've marked as acceptable answer to help someone else to go straight to the solution.

Comment: What if i need to use LocalDateTime instead?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` annotation to LocalDate variable solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind Model Objects which can be defined with simple types. when the object serialized from the client side to the server , It has no knowledge about the complex types(`like java.time.LocalDate`) unless they are expressed interms of simple types. For your scnerio the best way is to map the client side HTML with the server side java object Dates' as String. You can then convert the String object into `java.time.LocalDate` in the server side Controller class or any java service class.